# select whole word that is clicked in Windows

Tags: windows

Is there (Windows in-built?) way to select the whole word (as you would with ctrl+shift+arrow-left) with just the mouseclick? E.g. shift-mouse-left-click?

thanks

similar: [Selecting whole word using keyboard only](https://superuser.com/questions/346585/selecting-whole-word-using-keyboard-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Double-clicking on any word in nearly any Windows application will select the entire word.

Comment: indeed this is the correct answer. However I was implicitly looking for a keyboardshortcut to shift-mark multiple words. But on second thought this seems not really useful.

Comment: The keyboard "shortcut" is what you've already listed in your question, and your question states "...with just the mouseclick". I see that your "e.g." section may be a reference to this, but it is better to spell out precisely and specifically and clearly what you want. Think through what you have written and make sure it communicates everything you need very clearly without any jumped-to assumptions or missing information, and we'll be better able to explain and answer in a way satisfactory to you.